# Asynchronous functions and Firebase with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I read some questions about that. But I still have issues with asynchronous functions.

**For example:** I have a `viewController1` where a button perform a segue to a `viewController2`. In the `viewController2` class, I initialize some values in another class file named `exampleClass`. These values are retrieved  from Firebase database or location values. These values need a little moment to be retrieved. I return thes values from the `exampleClass` into my `viewController2`. I print these values in the `viewController2` `viewDidLoad()`.

**My issue:** The device doesn't wait that the values are retrieved and execute following functions. Result: When I touch the button, printed values are `nil` values. It can also make the app crash if I don't secure the code.

**What I've found so far:** I learned that I only have to call a func at the end of a Firebase `snapshot` (for example) like this:

```
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        self.name = snapshot.value as! String!
        print(self.name)
        self.forceEnd()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I named this function `forceEnd` to be clear. This is not working for me.  I also tried to create handlers but no positive results.

**My question:** How can I force the device to wait for the values to be retrieved before performing the following question?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I force the device to wait for the values to be retrieved before performing the following question?

- You don't want to *force* the device to wait, only need to perform some operations once *these values are retrieved from Firebase database*.
- Performing an operation asynchronously can be done in multiple ways like [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html), [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html), [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification), etc.

Generally, blocks are the more elegant approach.
Some sample code can be like:

```
func myFirebaseNetworkDataRequest(finished: () -> Void) { // the function thats going to take a little moment

     ...

     print("Doing something!") // firebase network request

     finished()    
}


// usage of above function can be as-

override func viewDidLoad() {

     myFirebaseNetworkDataRequest {

          // perform further operations here after data is fetched
          print("Finally! It took a lot of moments to end but now I can do something else.")
     }
}
```

Comment: That is not working. Here is my func:     `func initUserName(finished: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userRef = ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("name")
        
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            let name: String = snapshot.value as! String
            self.name = name
            finished()
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }        
    }`

Comment: Used like this:         `mainUser().initUserName() {
            print("data retrieved")
        }`